# Arrays.asList give UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, collections

The `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` can't be modified by using methods such as `add` or `remove`. But if you pass it to the `Collections.sort` method, it can sort the array without any problem (I expected an exception). This seems like a very inconsistent behaviour. So what are the allowed operations on the `List`, which returned by `asList` method?

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,7, 10 , 8,9);
list.remove(2);//Exception

Collections.sort(list);//Ok, No Exception Sort...
System.out.println(list);
```

I couldn't find any clue for this in the documentation.

**Edit:** Yes I can understand why it doesn't support `remove` or `add`. But then how can it support sorting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed size `List` backed by an array. Therefore `remove` and `add` are not supported. `set` is supported. You can look at this `List` as if it behaves exactly like an array. An array has a fixed length. You can't add or remove elements, but you can assign values to the indices of the array, which is equivalent to the `set` method of `List`. And you can sort an array.

`Collections.sort(list)` doesn't change the size of the `List`, so is can sort a fixed size list. All you need in order to sort a `List` is to swap elements of the `List`. For this purpose `set(index,element)` is sufficient.

All this information is found in the Javadoc of `Arrays` :

```
/**
 * Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.  (Changes to
 * the returned list "write through" to the array.)  This method acts
 * as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in
 * combination with {@link Collection#toArray}.  The returned list is
 * serializable and implements {@link RandomAccess}.
 *
 * <p>This method also provides a convenient way to create a fixed-size
 * list initialized to contain several elements:
 * <pre>
 *     List&lt;String&gt; stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param a the array by which the list will be backed
 * @return a list view of the specified array
 */
 public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

And if you look at an implementation of `Collections.sort`, you see that it actually sorts an array. The only `List` method it requires that modified the `List` is `set` of the `List`'s `ListIterator`, which calls the `List`'s `set(index,element)` method.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
  Object[] a = list.toArray();
  Arrays.sort(a);
  ListIterator<T> i = list.listIterator();
  for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
      i.next();
      i.set((T)a[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: With java 8, Collections.sort(List) is even smarter, it just delegates to the list itself for sorting. The default implementation in the List interface is basically the same as it was in Collections.sort() in Java 7; but the list now has the chance to avoid the extra array by implementing the sort as "in place". The Arrays.asList(...), as well as normal ArrayList do that by calling back Arrays.sort() on their internal storage array, for example.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList` gives you a `List` backed by **the array you give it**. Arrays are fixed size. The wrapping `List` supports the same operation that arrays do, so you can reassign the entries, but you can't change its length.