# Spring Beans: Can you add elements into an injected list?

Tags: spring, exception, collections, javabeans, code-injection

I am quite new at Spring Beans and I'm trying to build a rest controller that implements the CRUD operations.

I have a config file that has a @Bean that returns a list of **Book** type:

```
@Configuration
public class BookConfig {

    @Bean
    public static List<Book> books() {
        return Arrays.asList(
            new Book(1, "ABC", "Author ABC"),
            new Book(2, "DEF", "Author DEF"),
            new Book(3, "GHI", "Author GHI"));
    }
}
```

---

And the rest controller in which I constructor-injected the above Bean:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/books")
public class BookRestController {

    private List<Book> books;

    @Autowired
    public BookRestController(List<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }

    @PostMapping("")
    public void registerBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        books.add(book); // this throws **UnsupportedOperationException**
    }
}
```

---

At the POST method I try to add my **book** that comes from the request the my list of **books**, but I get an **UnsupportedOperationException**.

Is it just not possible to alter an injected collection or how should it be done?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1624144

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns an unmodifiable collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this with small steps again if this is for tutorial purposes.

- You can create a class that hosts the list.
- we can provide getter and setter methods in that class.
- Inject this class afterward.

Class would become

```
//BadNamedCLass
DataManager {
 private final List<Book> books = ArrayList<Book>();
 {
 // init block to add item to books if you want during initialization
 }
// getters
//setters
}
```

Config becomes:

```
@Configuration
public class BookConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataManager dataManager() {
        return new DataManager();
    }
}
```

Controller code becomes

```java
...
    @Autowired
    public BookRestController(DataManager dataManager) {
        this.dataManager= dataManager;
    }
...
```

For the exception please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174623/arrays-aslist-give-unsupportedoperationexception)

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to reply. That was quite fast tbh. I implemented the solution but still got the same error. It seems in the link that you provided that Arrays.asList() returns a fixed length list and that's why when I tried to add new elements it threw me that exception. Thank you, again!